# Sending form contents to cgiemail as well as external page

Tags: php, html, forms

I have a web page, and after  the contact form is submitted, the contents are sent to me via cgiemail. The page then redirects to a "success" page that tells the user that their query went through successfully. I would like to personalize this success page. I was wondering how I would go about creating a form that submits:

a) All of the form content via cgiemail
and b) sends some information (such as name) to the success page.

Thank you in advance.

Code sample: (Form)

```
<form id="ContactForm" method="post" action="http://website.com/cgi-bin/cgiemail/template.txt">
<div>
<div  class="wrapper">
  <span>Your Name:</span>
  <input name="yourname" class="input">
</div>
<div  class="wrapper">
  <span>Your E-mail:</span>
  <input name="email" class="input">                    
</div>
<div  class="textarea_box">
  <span>Your Message:</span>
  <textarea name="message"></textarea>
</div>
<a href="#" onClick="document.getElementById('ContactForm').submit()">Send</a>
</div>
<input type="hidden" name="success" value="http://website.com/successpage.php" />
</form>
```

I wish to submit the form to the email as done in the`action`, and that works perfectly. The next part, which I don't know how to approach, is submitting the information also to the page `successpage.php`,and using it there in a banner.

Comment: sorry, your question title is misleading, can you correct that? (You don't really submit form to multiple locations)

Comment: Please paste the code that sends the mail and does the redirect.

Comment: @Yankitwizzy, Hope that helps.

Comment: What is doing the redirect? Is the redirect working with the above code?

Comment: The `input` type at the end (I accidentally pasted the code that I was playing around with, the only changes are in the last 4 lines)

Comment: What happens when you submit the form. Which page does it goto?

Comment: It takes me to `http://website.com/successpage.php`

Comment: What is the content of the cgiemail script. I think with that I can tell you what to do

Comment: It's not a piece of code I have any part messing around with, it's standard. Aka, I don't know the inner workings of it, I just know it sends mail according to the template I fed it (which corresponds to the form). The emailing works all well and dandy, it's just passing the information elsewhere which I don't know how to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can user POST or GET for your main form to send additional data to your success page.

> feedback.php -> POST -> thankyou.php

In thankyou.php

- send email
- display thanks and data from feedback.php

What software are you using?

Comment: I'm coding in php and html, trying to avoid javascript as much as possible (since I'm relatively new to web programming), and I'm working in Dreamweaver.

Comment: I just did, a couple minutes ago.

Comment: Okay so in successpage.php reuse the variable that is used for sending the email. 

in successpage.php add <?php echo $_POST["yourname"];?> to display the name field, etc.

Answer (score 0):

On successful form submission and after you send yourself the email, instead of redirecting the user to a success page, you need to "generate" a page with PHP which contains all the information you want to show.

Here's a basic version of how your form submission page (PHP) should look like:

```
<html>
<head><title>Form submission</title></head>
<body>
<?
    /* validate data */

    if (validated_data) {
        send_email ();
?>
<b>Hi <? echo $_POST['yourname']; ?>, form submitted successfully!</b>
<?
    } else { 
?>
<b>Failed!</b>
<? } ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not try to make the form send parameters to two location. Let it send the info only to the page that sends the email, and then let that page redirect to your success page, passing some of the info as parameters.